# `)`was unexpected at this time.

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I am running a batch file on Windows 7 and running into this error (I have narrowed down the error to the following line):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('echo %RegVal%') do set sasroot=%%~sI
```

Where Regval is the file path of a given software, which in this case (on my Win7 machine) is:

```
RegVal = C:\Program Files\SAS 9.2_M3_10w37\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)
```

This same script used to work on Windows Vista, although I suspect it may be that there a parenthesis in RegVal now as it was previousy `C :\Program Files\SAS 9.2_M3_10w37\SASFoundation\` on my previous Vista machine.

Answer (score 3):

You suspection is correct.

To get around it, enclose your variable into doublequotes (You remove them again with the `~` in the `set`command)

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('echo "%RegVal%"') do set sasroot=%%~sI
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a file with the value of `RegVal` in it, then parse it using the `FOR` loop:

```
echo %RegVal%>C:\SomeFile.txt
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in (C:\SomeFile.txt) do set sasroot=%%~sI
```

This should help you get around your problem.

---

Stephan's solution is much simpler, but I'll explain my solution anyway, which might prove useful in some cases.

When the `FOR` command parses the data specified in the `IN` part using a command, it replaces the command with the result of the command, then runs the `FOR` command. For example, with the question above, the `FOR` command that will be executed after expanding `echo %RegVal%` is:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I in (C:\Program Files\SAS 9.2_M3_10w37\SASFoundation\9.2(32-bit)) do set sasroot=%%~sI
```

Thus, when the parser hits the first closing parenthesis, it will stop, thinking that everything it read before is the text to work on. However, in this case this is wrong, as the first closing parenthesis is part of the string to read; it doesn't indicate the end of the string.

When parsing a file with the `FOR` command, it will read each line, assign the predefined  tokens with the correct values, then execute the code block that follows. Rinse and repeat for every line in the file. But in this case, it will not replace the `IN` part with each line; it will only parse it and assign values to the tokens. This is the reason why special characters (such as parenthesis) do not create parsing errors in this case.

Comment: I do some batch file stuff, but couldn't exactly understand why/if this would work. Please could you edit your answer to show why your solution would work?

Comment: @zyboxinternational: it works, because the string with the problematic `)` is read from the file instead of being parsed.

Comment: @zyboxinternational Done. I hope it makes it clearer ;)